# multiple python decorators retrieve original function

Tags: python, decorator

I have a class running checks, each function performs a check. I have thought to decorators to add extra conditions, but this is maybe not wise.

I understand the concept of decorators, each taking as input the function it decorates and returning to the next one the function decorated. This is working well for instance for functions returning strings, as output can easily be edited by decorator and returned to the next decorator.

What I want to do is modify function attributes, putting for instance a `don't exec` flag for checks not to be run, `require auth` for checks performed only if authentication has been granted, or change a function attribute `order`, to sequence check launch.

```
# I return f only if is_authenticated flag is True
def auth_required(is_authenticated):
    def check_authentication(f):
        if is_authenticated:
            return f
    return check_authentication

# I edit order variable
def assignOrder(order):
    def do_assignment(f):
        f.order = order
        return f
    return do_assignment
# I instanciate Checks class and provide authentication;
# login and password will be tried and is_authenticat flag set accordingly
c = Checks(target, login, password)

# I sort on order variable and launch checks
functions = sorted(
    [
        getattr(c, field) for field in dir(c)
        if hasattr(getattr(c, field), 'order')
    ],key = (lambda field : field.order) 
)
for function in functions:
    function()

# I assign decorators so that order variable is set 
# I would like auth_required triggers launch if auth is performed
@auth_required(True)
@assignOrder(100)
def check_shares(self):
    # check defined here
```

This is working great for assignOrder, and my checks are launched in proper order.

But `@auth_required` is applied to `assignOrder` which is not what I want.

Is there a way to retrieve original function to be decorated? Or the usage of decorator is not relevant in this case? And what would be the solution?

Many thanks

Comment: "But @auth_required is applied to assignOrder which is not what I want."

Actually, `auth_required` is applied to "what `assignOrder` returned", not to `assignOrder` itself. What's your _real_ problem here actually ?

Comment: Thanks for answering; my problem is I can't set a `authenticated` flag and assign an `order` in the same time. I edit my question so that it is clearer

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get how your `auth_required` decorator is supposed to work ???

Comment: I authenticate user elsewhere and fill this decorator argument with the result of the authentication: `True` for granted and `False` for forbidden.

Comment: I still dont get how it's supposed to work, sorry. The way you define and apply `auth_require()`, your decorated function becomes `check_authentication(f)`. What this function do is : 1. check if `is_authenticated` is true - which will always be true since at this stage `is_authenticated` is the original function (the one you decorated with `auth_required()`) and a `function` object  has a true value in a boolean context -, then 2. return it's argument `f`.  This is obviously not what you expect, do you ???

Comment: Uhu seems like you edited your code snippet to pass an actual argument to `auth_required()` - but I still don't understand how you expect such an implementation to be useful. The first thing that feels wrong is to actually pass `is_authenticated` to the decorator, as it means you have to know if the user is authenticated at module import time - and it won't be able to authenticate later during the process's life. The other problem is that if `is_authenticated` is false, your inner function (the "real" decorator) returns `None` instead of a callable, which of course breaks all expectations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way of solving your problem. Decorators have no built-in facility to be cooperative, and don't even need to retain a reference to the original function.

So you need to come up with a protocol yourself, by e.g. making `assignOrder` save the original function to `do_assignment`.

Then in `is_authenticated`, you have to look if there is a "real" function behind the passed one, and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be confusing, despite you declaring you do undestand decorators.

I hope you undestand that if you do something like:

```
def auth_required(is_authenticated):
    def check_authentication(f):
        if is_authenticated:
            return f
    return check_authentication

@auth_required(something)
def my_function():
    ....
```

Means that the "something" variable is checked at import time, and only once, and your decorated function will be supressed - that is the name "mu_function"  will be bound to `None`, causing an error in any code that tries to call that. If you replace the return None to return a function that does nothing instead, to work around that error, this would still not be changeable until you re-load the module containing the function (in a tests scenario, this usually means running everything again).

So, this is not just wrong - it indicates you *are* confused by whta decorators do at all.

It would be simpler to rely on a global variale to turn the funcion on and off this way:

```
from functools import wraps
def auth_required(f):
   @wraps(f)
   def wrapper (*args, **kw):
       if is_authenticated:
            return f(*args, **kw)
       return None
   return wrapper
```

Now, this decorators can turn your decorated function "on" and "off" at will by changing the `is_authenticated` module level variable at run time between calls - no module reloading needed.

Also, going back to your title question on "multiple python decorators retrieve original function": 
note I added teh `functools.wraps` decorator to the wrapper code itself above. This function in recent Python's sets a  `__wrapped__` attribute on the decorated function that points to your original decorated function to start with.

So, if all your decorators are well behaved and apply `functools.wraps` on their wrappers, you can always have access to the innermost function by 
using its `__wrapped__` attribute.